# Firebase auth google provider popup (and redirect) gives blank page

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to set up firebase auth for my next js project, and while it works to sign in and login with email og password, google sign in does not, it opens popup (or redirects if use signInWithRedirect()) but the popup is empty. Does not show my google accounts. Just loads an empty screen from 'https://project.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler?apiKey=blablabla&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D&authType=signInViaPopup&redirectUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Flogin&v=9.16.0&providerId=google.com&scopes=profile'

A weird part is that it worked for a short while earlier, but then at some point it stopped, and I don't now what I changed, if I changed anything at all. Tried resetting back to old code, and also setting up new firebase project, but does not work anymore.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "blabla",
    authDomain: "project.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "project",
    storageBucket: "project.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "blabla",
    appId: "blabla",
    measurementId: "blabla"
}

// Use this to initialize the firebase App
export const firebaseClient = !firebase.apps.length
  ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  : firebase.app();

// Use these for db & auth
export const db = firebaseClient.firestore()
export const auth = firebaseClient.auth()

export const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()

export default firebaseClient
```

this is signin functions (with mail & password works):

```
function signIn(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (emailRef.current && passwordRef.current) {
      auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        emailRef.current.value,
        passwordRef.current.value
      ).then((authUser) => {
        console.log(authUser)

        router.push('/dashboard/profile')
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message)
      })
      console.log("signin", emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
    }
  }

  function signInGoogle(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) {
    e.preventDefault()

    auth.signInWithRedirect(googleProvider)
    .then((authUser) => {
      console.log(authUser)

      router.push('/dashboard')
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert(error.message)
    })
  }
```

EDIT:
Here is some more info:
The only errors I get are these cookie issues:
[image: cookie issues]

I also however get another error when connecting to my firestore, which maybe is correlated??

[image: Firestore error]

this is the code for that (which logs no products...):

```
useEffect(()=>{
        db.collection('products').where('active','==', true).get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(async (product) => {
                console.log(product.data);
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(error.message)
        })
    }, [])
```

Comment: Have you checked for any errors in browser console either in the pop up or redirected tab?

Comment: Hi, I added some more info in the question now. There are some cookie issues, but not any errors in the console